# Server error when attempting to access activity tab of network profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, 500-server-error

When I went to my StackExchange profile, Everything seems fine, but when you click on the activity tab, this shows up

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Is this just my device or others too?

[image]

To reproduce, go to https://stackexchange.com/users/current (whilst logged in)
and then click the activity tab

Comment: Reproduced (on several users). Someone added new enum members & forgot to update a switch... Devs are workin' on it!

Comment: @Shog9 No worries. Lesson learned for the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We added a few new activity types to the database for other purposes today, and neglected to revise the query and code that handles the activity list. We probably don't want to pull down every upvote and downvote here (it's your *public* list of activities...) and the code certainly wasn't expecting them to come back from the DB... But we were, and so the code saw the new IDs and threw an exception.

With an updated query in place and a new build rolled out, you should now be able to review your activities without interruption.

Big thanks for the report and your patience!

Comment: It's really good to see that even if you did a mistake that exposes privacy to some degree, some system validates it and throws an exception. Anyways, thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: What are the new activity types?

Comment: D*mn upgrades, always get you ;-)